# Question about performance and optimization

Tags: java

How inefficient is that:

```
List<Object> getList(){
    return new LinkedList<Object>();
}

void foo(){
    for(Object o: getList()){
       do something with o;
    }
}
```

in compare with that:

```
List<Object> getList(){
    return new LinkedList<Object>();
}

void foo(){
    List<Object>  os = getList();
    for(Object o: os){
       do something with o;
    }
}
```

Comment: No difference. Likely the generated bytecode will be near identical for the two.

Comment: I assume you speculate whether `getList()` gets called more than once in the first version? If so, answer is no: it gets called once in both versions, and there is no difference in performance.

Comment: The first is about 16 chars more efficient (to type).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There won't be any perceptible difference.

I've compiled the following code:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test1 {

    static List<Object> getList(){
        return new LinkedList<Object>();
    }

    void process(Object o) {}

    void foo1(){
        for(Object o: getList()){
            process(o);
        }
    }

    void foo2(){
        List<Object>  os = getList();
        for(Object o: os){
            process(o);
        }
    }
}
```

The bytecodes for `foo1` and `foo2` are as follows:

```
void foo1();
  Code:
   0:   invokestatic    #26; //Method getList:()Ljava/util/List;
   3:   invokeinterface #28,  1; //InterfaceMethod java/util/List.iterator:()Ljava/util/Iterator;
   8:   astore_2
   9:   goto    24
   12:  aload_2
   13:  invokeinterface #34,  1; //InterfaceMethod java/util/Iterator.next:()Ljava/lang/Object;
   18:  astore_1
   19:  aload_0
   20:  aload_1
   21:  invokevirtual   #40; //Method process:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
   24:  aload_2
   25:  invokeinterface #42,  1; //InterfaceMethod java/util/Iterator.hasNext:()Z
   30:  ifne    12
   33:  return

void foo2();
  Code:
   0:   invokestatic    #26; //Method getList:()Ljava/util/List;
   3:   astore_1
   4:   aload_1
   5:   invokeinterface #28,  1; //InterfaceMethod java/util/List.iterator:()Ljava/util/Iterator;
   10:  astore_3
   11:  goto    26
   14:  aload_3
   15:  invokeinterface #34,  1; //InterfaceMethod java/util/Iterator.next:()Ljava/lang/Object;
   20:  astore_2
   21:  aload_0
   22:  aload_2
   23:  invokevirtual   #40; //Method process:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
   26:  aload_3
   27:  invokeinterface #42,  1; //InterfaceMethod java/util/Iterator.hasNext:()Z
   32:  ifne    14
   35:  return
```

As you can see for yourself, the bytecodes for the two loops are identical. The only difference is that `foo2` stores and loads the list reference in a local variable at the start.

One might argue that a better optimizing compiler may be able to eliminate `os` altogether, producing identical code for both functions.

Comment: This isn't really relevant to the question, but any idea why in the bytecode the condition is placed below the loop body and it's `goto`'d (`goneto`?) the first time?

Comment: @Bart van Heukelom: Beats me.

Answer (score 5):

In

```
for(Object o: getList()) {
```

`getList()` is an expression that is evaluated once and its result (a reference an `iterator` of the list) kept. If you fear that this code calls `getList()` at each iteration, it is not true (if it was, it would be an infinite loop if the list had at least one element as each time the iteration would start with a new list, at the 0 element).

Comment: There's not really a direct reference to the list kept, but rather an `Iterator` is created from it (which has, of course, a reference to the list, but you know what I mean). That doesn't matter for this question though.

Answer (score 4):

As this:

```
List<Object>  os = getList();
```

only creates a reference and the actual data is not copied, the difference in speed is negligible, perhaps non-existant because it probably will be the same bytecode.

Comment: In fact, IMHO there is absolutely no difference in speed. In the second form, the return value from getList (the reference to the list) gets written into the stack by the compiler (after evaluating the expression). The only difference is that "variable" cannot be referenced by the code.

Answer (score 0):

In fact the former is more efficient in theory, because in the latter there is one more reference created.

However this is negligible (really negligible) difference.